# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc, runtime-error, apache-poi

I'm Using *Apache POI* to read some Excel files.  I've created a console application to do the job, after that I've tried to integrate the code in a *Spring MVC* webApp (nothing special, I know). I've included the same Jar files to my *Classpath*, but whenever I try to run the code, I got this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font
```

I believe that the class Font was found during compilation time, but not at runtime. I'm pretty sure that the problem is not with the *ClassPath*, but I can't figure out how to solve this.

EDIT : When I copy the same code in a new class with main method (in the same web project), and run my web app as a console java app, it works.

Comment: did you add the JAR to the run path ?

Comment: Yes! The jar files are properly Added to the BuildPath ...

Comment: how are you building you application ? Maven , Ivy / IDE or command line.

Comment: I'm Using Eclipe And Maven, for some reasons, I'm pushed to use the POI Jar files independently of the Maven dependencies.. I made sure that there is no version mismatches in my builPath Jars.

Comment: Which version of POI do you use?

Comment: Can you explain why including it in the Build path has anything to do with it being available in the runtime classpath?

Comment: All I know is the *NoClassDefFoundError* is due to this issue, when the class is not correctly located by the ClassLoader at runtime, but the jar itself is present when i compile the app.

Comment: Do you have all required jar files? If you want to process the "newer" (OOXML) Excel files (.xlsx), you also need poi-ooxml and poi-ooxml-schemas . If it is the same as with the Word files, a "newer" Excel file may have the extension .xls but actually is an .xlsx (so to speak).

Comment: Well, as I said, my code was working, I'm working with xlsx files, And my program was working with the same Jar files (ooxml jars are already included).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue do the following :

1 - check if your Pom.xml doesn't contain any of the Apache POI dependencies.

2 - delete poi folder from your Maven repository.

3 - run your project as a maven clean

4 - update project

5 - Import again you poi Jars to your classpath

6 - run and enjoy